# Determining the probability of multiple condtional events

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

(I hope I used the correct terminology, I am a social sciences guy, not a math guy, and I am a bit out of my element. Please be kind.)

I am trying to determine the cumulative probability of two finite events with three possible outcomes.

To put it in simple terms, what is the cumulative probability of failure, failure being a roll of a 1 or 2 on a six sided die.

IE: Individual rolls a die, and gets a 1 (failure), and then rolls a second die 3 (success...)

Individual 2 rolls a die, and gets a failure on both rolls, and individual 3 succeeds on both rolls.

How do I calculate the aggregate chance that nothing will happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "the aggregate chance that nothing will happen"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a couple of things that you haven't fully specified. First of all, the probability of each of the 3 outcomes, and secondly, whether the events are indepedent or not (i.e., whether the outcome of the first event in any way influences the outcome of the second).

In your example, these are answerable: the three outcomes (A = 1 or 2, B = 3 or 4, C = 5 or 6) are equally probable, and so each has a probability of $1/3$. And the outcome of the second roll is not affected by the first. There are 9 possible outcomes of the two rolls, each having probability = $\frac 1 3 \times\frac 1 3 = \frac 1 9$: $$AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC$$

If we consider $A$ a failure, then note that there are $5$ combinations including $A$, so the probability of failure will be $\frac 5 9$.

Comment: That answered it perfectly, thank you!